# Converting JSON to an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable that contains the following JSON string:

```
{
    "0" : "Jun 20, 2012 03:02 PM",
    "1" : "Jun 20, 2012 03:26 PM",
    "2" : "Jun 21, 2012 01:12 PM",
    "3" : "Jun 21, 2012 01:25 PM",
    "4" : "Jun 21, 2012 02:42 PM",
    "5" : "Jun 21, 2012 02:43 PM",
    "6" : "NULL"
}
```

I wish to convert this JSON to an array in javascript such that 
array[0] has "Jun 20, 2012 03:02 PM" array[1] has "Jun 20, 2012 03:26 PM" and so on.

Comment: Why bother reassigning it? As an object, you can already access it via syntax like `object[0]` (unless you need array iteration using `.length`)

Comment: @Michael because objects have a specific purpose as a data structure, as do arrays. In this case I'd say an array makes much more semantic sense. Granted, if it comes at a performance cost, who knows.

Comment: Not to be a wiener but this is an object, not a JSON object.

Comment: @Cecchi I agree it would be better as an array.

Comment: If you are in control of the code that produces this object, (if it is supplied by an API or whatever) can you encode it as an array in the first place?

Comment: jsonObj[i]  gives me character values like " { and on .. the array size is 201

Comment: Then `jsonObj` really contains a JSON string? This is not clear from your question! You have to parse that string into an object first. Then you can access it with `jsonObj[0]`, `jsonObj[1]`, etc.

Comment: Oh, I totally didn't get this. Somebody reject my edits.

Comment: Yep. @ddlshack: Apparently the OP really has a string containing JSON (I approved your edit, but before I knew that).

Comment: @FelixKling  my code is var jsonObj ={/literal}{$json}{literal};
           document.write(jsonObj);

Comment: document. write gives me 



{"0" : "Jun 20, 2012 03:02 PM", "1" : "Jun 20, 2012 03:26 PM", "2" : "Jun 21, 2012 01:12 PM", "3" : "Jun 21, 2012 01:25 PM", "4" : "Jun 21, 2012 02:42 PM", "5" : "Jun 21, 2012 02:43 PM", "6" : "NULL" }

Comment: var currentVersion = {/literal} {$displayedVersion} {literal};
           var jsonObj = eval('(' + {/literal}{$json}{literal} + ')');
           

worked

Comment: AUGGHH - `eval` is evil.

Comment: Don't use eval to parse JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var currentVersion = {/literal} {$displayedVersion} {literal};
           var jsonObj = eval('(' + {/literal}{$json}{literal} + ')');

Comment: I find this answer confusing; can you clarify or elaborate?

Comment: i was not creating JSONObject in Javascript. I was simply trying to access the JSON .. instead i was trying to access JSON String

Answer (score 5):

You must parse your JSON string into a javascript object first.

**JavaScript**

```
var object = JSON.parse(JSONString);
```

To polyfill browsers without JSON support:
http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/

---

Then, convert that object to an array:

**JavaScript**

```
var arr = [];
for(var i in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        arr.push(object[i]);
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var arr = $.map(obj,function(value){ return value; });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/MD3pF/

Note: Since the original poster did not mention jQuery it is worth mentioning that loading jQuery for only these instances isn't worthwhile, and you would be better off using the pure JavaScript if you aren't already using jQuery.

Comment: No problem, one full answer is better than two partial answers ;)

Comment: Not so sure about that `$.makeArray` idea--it doesn't really give you the array access I *think* the OP is looking for.

Comment: @iambriansreed: Seriously, you're hijacking answers to post unsolicited jQuery solutions? That's really poor.

Comment: Its not really hijacking, and jQuery is so common that I think it deserves a mention.

Comment: @ddlshack: jQuery is entirely irrelevant to the question if OP isn't already using it. It's really obnoxious when people try to inject jQuery into every freaking JavaScript question. Even more so when it isn't even your answer.

Comment: He might be already using it. And theres a pure javascript version too. Additional information never hurts.

Comment: @ddlshack I have to agree with amnotiam--it's weird to edit someone *else's* on-topic answer to add a jQuery answer, IMO. Not that it matters, really.

Comment: @ddlshack: It's just so annoying when jQuery fanboys feel the need to promote it at every turn. The fact that OP "might" be using it is irrelevant. OP might be using one of a hundred libraries.

Comment: So the complaint is that I added information to someone's post who appreciated the change. O.K. Wow. And you might want to look away I added more jQuery. @ddlshack that update cool?

Comment: @iambriansreed: No, the complaint is that it is obnoxious behavior to inject jQuery as a solution to a JavaScript question that makes no mention of it. And it's absolutely over the top to go around and do it to other people's posts.

Comment: @iambriansreed: And you're corrupting the quality of the answer. The suggestion to use jQuery as a polyfill for `JSON.parse` is ***terrible*** advice. It makes no sense to load a bloated DOM manipulation library just to get its JSON support. Now I have to down-vote, because the answer gives bad advice. Way to go,

Comment: @amnotiam I just made a note. I totally agree with you. [Most folks are using jQuery now](http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery) and it behooves them to use a one liner jQuery function if they are already loading jQuery. In the future I won't interject my jQuery fascinations on other's posts.

Comment: I agree with @amnotiam about advising to use jQuery for JSONParse. The other bit can stay in case he happens to be using jQuery.

Comment: @all thank you for your comments. and i was not using jQuery. Though i could have used DoJo. This was one of the thing used in our env. Anyways it got solved by JS only. Thanks all for your comments. I have learned quiet a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you're targeting ES5 and above:

```
// myObject = { '0': 'a', '1': 'b' };
var myArray = Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) { return myObject[key]; });
// myArray = [ 'a', 'b' ];
```